# Can't read property of undefined (mix.initialize() )when use node_modules/.bin/webpack

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm trying to compile with `node_modules/.bin/webpack` and I get this error:

```
Mix.initialize();       
   ^       
TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined      
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/Code/stream/webpack.config.js:9:4)            
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)      
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)      
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)  
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)      
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)       
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)      
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)      
at requireConfig 
(/home/vagrant/Code/stream/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:97:18)     
at /home/vagrant/Code/stream/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:104:17
```

**webpack.mix.js**:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix').mix;       
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')      
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

**webpack.config.js**:

```
var path = require('path');       
var webpack = require('webpack');      
var Mix = require('laravel-mix').config;    
var plugins = require('laravel-mix').plugins;    
Mix.initialize();
```

I'm following this video: https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/26?autoplay=true

And crash at 03:29, i really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, finally i do it.

In video he remove some package of package.json at the beginning. (laravel-mix included) and after this he install laravel-mix 0.3 version.

So when i create the laravel project i don't remove laravel-mix (the version is "0.*". If i do that and i run npm run dev always is good.

I can't understand why he remove package and install it before, and do

```
cp -r node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/** ./
```

Hope that's usefull to somebody.

Comment: The latest version is 1.2.0, I wouldn't stick with a such old version (0.3)

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of laravel-mix you don't need require mix property. According library [documentation](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/docs/installation.md) you just need in webpack.mix.js file:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
```

Also in package.json in section scripts you should have path to your vendor file with laravel-mix (if you don't need custom config), for example:

```
  "scripts": {
     "dev": "webpack --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
```

Comment: Hi Jaroslav, thanks for your answer. I know i don't need .mix. Also my node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js is not my ./webpack.config.js cause i edit it. If i put this on package.json: "dev": "webpack --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=webpack.config.js" and run npm run dev have the same error..

Answer (score 2):

I was following the same video. Here are the steps I took to get past this same error:

1. $`laravel new stream --dev`
2. $`cd stream`
3. $`npm install`
4. $`npm install babel-loader sass-loader vue-loader --save-dev`
5. $`cp node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js ./`
6. Open up ./webpack.config.js and make it look like this:

   ```
   require('./node_modules/laravel-mix/src/index');
   require(Mix.paths.mix());
   Mix.dispatch('init', Mix);
   let WebpackConfig = require('./node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/WebpackConfig');
   module.exports = new WebpackConfig().build();
   ```
7. $`node_modules/.bin/webpack`
8. Pick it up around 1:32 in the video

I'm running into more issues in the video as well. If I find solutions to those, I'll update this answer.

Comment: Perfect, if you have any question you can create a new question, and attach the link here, maybe i can help you.

Comment: Thanks! Here's my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081484/vuejs-router-failed-to-mount-component-template-or-render-function-not-defined

Comment: After big research this helped me alot, Thank you!

Comment: This is the solution ! Thanks !