# VueJS Router 'Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.'

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm following this video: https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/26?autoplay=true

My initial problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45011694/cant-read-property-of-undefined-mix-initialize-when-use-node-modules-bin-w), but that was resolved. I include it here so you can see what steps I've taken so far.

Now, I'm getting this warning: [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

A warning is not so bad, but the router-view is not showing up. That is, there is nothing showing up below the Home and About links.

master.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>My App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
            <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>

            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
        <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Home Page</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        I'm an example component!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

[Edit 1]

resources/assets/js/app.js

```
import './bootstrap';
import router from './routes';


new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import axios from 'axios';

window.Vue = Vue;
Vue.use(VueRouter);

window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

[Edit 2]

resources/assets/js/routes.js

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';


let routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: require('./views/Home.vue')
    }
];

export default new VueRouter({
    routes
});
```

Comment: Can you show what you have in `js/app.js`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I added my app.js and bootstrap.js files.

Comment: Do you have templates or components for your routes in `routes.js VueRouter`.

Comment: Sorry - I should've included that as well. I just updated my question to include my routes.js file

Comment: That brings as to `/views/Home.vue` :)

Comment: Thanks so much for holding my hand down the path. /facepalm/ I think I've discovered the answer. See below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! Thanks to [TheFallen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5829529/thefallen)'s questions, I see my problem. Here's what my routes.js file should look like:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from './views/Home.vue';

let routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Home
    }
];

export default new VueRouter({
    routes
});
```